# How do I fetch a data from an external database into my wordpress home

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a WordPress site installed in a subfolder of my host and another old site in the public_HTML. I'll like to fetch some data (a marquee text to be used around the header on the index of my WordPress home) from the old site to the new site(note, the two sites have a different database). I already have a php code that fetches the data.

```php
//test.php

<?php
include_once("admin/includes/config.php");
include_once("admin/includes/db.class.php");    
$db = new DB; $db -> open();
$strScrollingText = '';
$db -> query("select * from anouncements where status = 1 
order by id desc");
if ($db -> rows() > 0)
        {
    $strScrollingText .= '<MARQUEE scrolldelay="100" 
direction="left">';
    while ($rs = $db -> rsset())
    $strScrollingText .= stripslashes($rs['anouncement']) . ', 
';
    $strScrollingText .= '</MARQUEE>';      
    }

?>
```

When test.php above is placed in my root directory and ran, it outputs a marquee text from the database. Then I moved the file into my themes folder (of course, I adjusted the db include file path using ../)  and tried to include the test.php using include('test.php); in the `<head>` of my theme's header.php, but when I refreshed my homepage, it was blank. I even copied the content of test.php into the `<head>` and removed the 'echo $strScrolling text; ' and place it where and want it to appear but the homepage was still blank. I also use the the #include directive in my Themes functions.php but this made my whole WordPress crash (I had to go and edit the file through cpanel to restore my wp).
I don't know where am doing this wrong and it's really frustrating and I need any help I can get. I would even appreciate if I can get this done using a plugin.

Comment: You sould have a dev env to enable exception error.

Comment: if you copied only what your're showing, then it's now full code. in php, or wordpress there isn't default`class DB`, which you're trying to call with this line `$db = new DB; $db -> open();`.

Comment: I can guess, they are `admin/includes/config.php` and `admin/includes/db.class.php` files. you should also copy them

Comment: I Dont get? I already added an absolute path ../../../../admin/includes/config.php and ../../../../admin/includes/db.class.php to the test.php file so I think it should link up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something similar to the below? Create a new WPDB instance and use its methods in order to make sure that you are using a Class that is already included in wordpress.  Also I would suggest to enable `WP_DEBUG` in your `wp-config.php` to have an idea what error is being caused.

Also I would suggest that you set the wpdb parameters harcoded at first in order to avoid including the files from root folder, just to make sure that they are not causing any errors. If everything works than try to include the other files and therefore you can evaluate if the files included are causing any issues.

```
$db = new wpdb( EXTERNAL_DB_USERNAME, EXTERNAL_DB_PASS, EXTERNAL_DB_NAME, EXTERNAL_DB_HOST );
$strScrollingText = '';
$sql = "select * from anouncements where status = 1 order by id desc";
$results = $db->get_results($sql);
if ( count($results) > 0 ){

    $strScrollingText .= '<MARQUEE scrolldelay="100" direction="left">';

    foreach ($results as $row){
        $strScrollingText .= stripslashes($row->anouncement) . ', ';
    }

    $strScrollingText .= '</MARQUEE>';      

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have solved it already with a similar code and I tried to post the answer here, but I gave up when I couldn't. I used the helper get_var() instead since all I need is the latest announcement.